# Openfire missing messages when I was in another activity in android app

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, openfire, smack

I have implemented smack library in my android code for connecting with openfire server. It is working nice. But I have an issue with getting chat message when I am in another activity. Even if I enter the chat window I missed those message (while I was in another activity). Chat is working perfect when I am in the chat window with the second user.

I am using Smack version 4.1.0 alpha 6.

Comment: I'm using ver 4.2.2 and all functions works perfectly. give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

maybe because your connection is not persistent through out the app . you can implement 
`ConnectionListener` interface of smack and also implement `StanzaListener`. run a background service to make the connection persistent and listen for incoming messages